# Handling errors in multiple calls of AngularJS promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I have an AngularJS service with such async API:

```
myService.asyncCall(['id0', 'id3', 'id2']).then(function (complexData) {   
  // handle complexData
}).catch(function (error) {   
  console.log(error); 
});
```

`asyncCall` incapsulates multiple calls of `$http` which handled by `$q.all`. Each of the `$http` requests can response with error and I want the errors to be handled by one `catch` handler. So how i can achieve multiple calls of the `catch` handler ?

Comment: `$q.all` gets rejected when any of the promises gets rejected. What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, Yes, But I want to handle each possible reject from the  promises array that I pass to `$q.all`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want to achieve (that's why I asked for clarification). What exactly doyou mean by _"handle each possible reject from the promises array"_.

Comment: Ok, forgot about `$q.all`. I want my `asyncCall` 
1. to get array of promises, 
2. has one resolve handler for each resolved promise from the array (`then` block from the example)
3. has one reject handler that will be called for each rejected promise. (`catch` block from the example). I hope now it is clear.

Comment: I still have questions :) 1. Do you want the requests to happen in parallel, sequentially, or whatever ? 2. What do you want to happen when any of the requests fails ? Continue with the rest or abort all ? 3. I understand that you want to have two functions: 1 for handling the success of any request and one for handing the error of any request (so if 3 requests succeed, your success handler should be called 3 times). Is that correct or am I still missing the point ?

Comment: 1. parallel, just like `$q.all` would call them.
2. I want `catch`to be called with the error and continue with the rest.
3. Not really. success should be called one time and `complexData` should be array (sorry for missing it earlier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly (finally), this is what you are trying to achieve:

- Input:

  1. a list of promises
  2. a callback to be called when all promises have been resolved
  3. a callback to be called each time any of the promises gets rejected

---

- Behaviour:

  1. You want parallel execution (not sequential).
  2. You want all promises to be either resolved or rejected (i.e. even if one promise gets rejected, the rest should continue as usual).
  3. You want the "final" callback to be called exactly once (receiving an array of results - regardless if the respective deferred was resolved or rejected).

---

`$q.all` should be "augmented" to suit your needs, because by default:

1. It gets immediatelly rejected as soon as any of the promises in the list gets rejected.
2. In case of rejection it returns only the rejection reason and **not** a list of results.

---

Here is a possible implementation:

```
function asyncCall(listOfPromises, onErrorCallback, finalCallback) {

  listOfPromises  = listOfPromises  || [];
  onErrorCallback = onErrorCallback || angular.noop;
  finalCallback   = finalCallback   || angular.noop;

  // Create a new list of promises that can "recover" from rejection
  var newListOfPromises = listOfPromises.map(function (promise) {
    return promise.catch(function (reason) {

      // First call the `onErrroCallback`
      onErrorCallback(reason);

      // Change the returned value to indicate that it was rejected
      // Based on the type of `reason` you might need to change this
      // (e.g. if `reason` is an object, add a `rejected` property)
      return 'rejected:' + reason;

    });
  });

  // Finally, we create a "collective" promise that calls `finalCallback` when resolved.
  // Thanks to our modifications, it will never get rejected !
  $q.all(newListOfPromises).then(finalCallback);
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/mg2cU/)**.

Comment: Yes, Almost what I am looking for but with the only exception that I need only resolved results without rejected ones in success handler. Any ideas how can change your `all` modification?

Comment: It is generally not very usefull to remove some results, because then there will be no way to know which result belongs to which promise. In any case, you could filter the results before passing them to `finalCallback`. E.g. replace `.then(finalCallback)` with `.then(function(results){finalCallback(results.filter(function(res){return res.indexOf('rejected:') !== 0;}));})`.

Comment: What if I need the finalCallback to be executed only if there are no rejected promises???

Comment: @ppollono: Add a flag that is set to true before the `onErrorCallback()` is called and check it before calling `finalCallback`. It really depends on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One way, would be to attach a `.catch` handler indidually in your service:

```
function asyncCall(urls){
    var calls = urls.map(makeSomeCall).
                map(function(prom){ return prom.catch(e){ /* recover here */});
    return $q.all(calls);
};
```

Another way would be to implement a `settle` method that is like `$q.all` but keeps track of all results. Stealing from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317555/):

```
function settle(promises){
     var d = $q.defer();
     var counter = 0;
     var results = Array(promises.length);
     promises.forEach(function(p,i){ 
         p.then(function(v){ // add as fulfilled
              results[i] = {state:"fulfilled", promise : p, value: v};
         }).catch(function(r){ // add as rejected
              results[i] = {state:"rejected", promise : p, reason: r};
         }).finally(function(){  // when any promises resolved or failed
             counter++; // notify the counter
             if (counter === promises.length) {
                d.resolve(results); // resolve the deferred.
             }
         });
     });
})
```

You can handle multiple promises as such:

```
var promiseArr = ["id0","id3","id2"].map(makePromise);

settle(promiseArr).then(function(results){
    var failed = results.filter(function(r){ return r.state === "rejected"; });
    var failedValues = failed.map(function(i){ return i.value; });
    var done = results.filter(function(r){ return r.state === "fulfilled"; });
     var doneValues = done.map(function(i){ return i.value; }); 
});
```

Which gives you access to all results of the promise, regardless if it failed or not, and let you recover with more granularity.

Your service should handle that aggregation since it's the one returning a promise on everything. One example would be to do:

```
if(failed.length > 0){
     throw new Error("The following failed..."); // some info about all failed
}
```

Comment: What if I want to show error notification each time when `$http` answers with error ? That is why i want multiple calls of `catch`

Comment: Look at the first approach I suggested. That should do it.

Comment: Thought about such solution, but in this case `then` handler will not be called if at least one of promises will be rejected (because of `all` behaviour). In other words in need kind of `all` that will call `then` for all resolved promises and `catch` for **each** rejected promise.

Comment: How would it look in synchronous code? @e.gluhotorenko