# Keeping track and progress of various ajax post requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar, promise

I'm using jQuery to make various ajax POST requests. I need to keep track of the success or failure of each one of them, along with the overall progress of the complete batch, so that I can update the UI with a progress bar and info about how many requests have succeeded, and how many have failed, out of the total.

Before attempting to implement the feature in my app, I've been playing with some code in jsfiddle as a proof of concept, with no luck so far. This is what I've got:

```
// an alternative to console.log to see the log in the web page
var fnLog = function(message) {
    $('#console').append($("<p>" + message + "</p>"));
};

// keeping track of how many ajax calls have been finished (successfully or not)
var count = 0;

// a dummy ajax call that succeeds by default
var fn = function(shouldFail) {
    return $.get(shouldFail ? '/echo/fail/' : '/echo/json/')
        .done(function() { fnLog("done") })
        .fail(function() { fnLog("FAIL") });
};

// a set of different asynchronous ajax calls
var calls = [fn(),fn(),fn(),fn(true),fn(),fn()];

// an attempt to make a collective promise out of all the calls above
$.when.apply($, calls)
    .done(function() { fnLog("all done") })
    .fail(function() { fnLog("ALL FAIL") })
    .always(function() { fnLog("always") })
    .progress(function(arg) { fnLog("progress" + arg) })
    .then(function() { fnLog("finished") });
```

It's all in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmtbo7v6/1/

What I need is the ability to provide a callback that ought to be called after all promises are resolved (either successfully or not).

When all calls above are set to succeed (by removing the `true` argument to the fourth `fn` call in the array) it works fine. The output prints the following:

```
done
done
done
done
done
done
all done
always
finished
```

But when even a single call is set to fail (as it is by default in the jsfiddle), the output is the following:

```
done
FAIL
ALL FAIL
always
done
done
done
done
```

So none of the collective promise callbacks (the one generated by the `$.when` call) is called after all promises are resolved. The final `.then` is not called at all if a single ajax call fails.

Additionally, I would appreciate some insight on how to keep track of the progress of this batch of ajax calls, to update a progress bar in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I'm going to be unfair. jQuery actually comes bundled with progression events but I myself hate them because I don't think they compose or aggregate well - so I'll show a simpler alternative approach for that progress bar that I [believe is superior](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#progression-migration) instead.

First thing's first:

The 'all promises resolved but some possibly rejected' issue is called a 'settle' typically. I've provided an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617895/ignoring-ajax-errors-with-promises-array-and-when) with just giving the results and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23318215/1348195) providing an implementation that gives you access to all results even rejected ones.

```
 function settle(promises){
     var d = $.Deferred();
     var counter = 0;
     var results = Array(promises.length);
     promises.forEach(function(p,i){ 
         p.then(function(v){ // add as fulfilled
              results[i] = {state:"fulfilled", promise : p, value: v};
         }).catch(function(r){ // add as rejected
              results[i] = {state:"rejected", promise : p, reason: r};
         }).always(function(){  // when any promises resolved or failed
             counter++; // notify the counter
             if (counter === promises.length) {
                d.resolve(results); // resolve the deferred.
             }
         });
     });
     return d.promise();
 }
```

You'd use `settle` in place of `$.when` to get your desired results.

As for progression - I personally recommend passing a progression callback to the method itself. The pattern goes something like this:

```
function settle(promises, progress){
     progress = progress || function(){}; // in case omitted
     var d = $.Deferred();
     var counter = 0;
     var results = Array(promises.length);
     promises.forEach(function(p,i){ 
         p.then(function(v){ // add as fulfilled 
              results[i] = {state:"fulfilled", promise : p, value: v};
         }).catch(function(r){ // add as rejected
              results[i] = {state:"rejected", promise : p, reason: r};
         }).always(function(){  // when any promises resolved or failed
             counter++; // notify the counter
             progress((promises.length - counter) / promises.length);
             if (counter === promises.length) {
                d.resolve(results); // resolve the deferred.
             }
         });
     });
     return d.promise();
 }
```

Which would let you do something like:

```
settle([url1, url2, ... url100].map($.get), function(soFar){
    $("#myProgressBar").css("width", (soFar * 100)+"%");
}).then(function(results){
    console.log("All settled", results);
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Benjamin. I was already suspecting that the inherent way in which promises work would not serve my purpose, but I had not find a way to solve it. Your answer doesn't only solves my problem, but it gives me more insight on how to use jQuery's `$.Deferred` for my own purposes and to achieve custom behavior like the one that I need on this particular case. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @Benjamin, I've been implementing the progress part of this, and I dug a little more on the jQuery way of doing it, which you say you consider inferior. I'm curious about why, because it's actually pretty simple to integrate into the code you show above, without having to pass a second arg to the `settle` function. Then after incrementing the `counter` in the `always` callback, you can call `d.notify(counter, promises.length)` instead of your own `progress` callback. Finally, you can register progress callbacks to the returned promise, and they'll be called whenever `d.notify` is called.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there's a much better alternative to this problem, one which shadows the promises approach. Behold the combination of two patterns: Observables + Iterables = Reactive programming.

Reactive Programming is programming with asynchronous data streams, that is, treating asynchronous data streams as collections that can be traversed and transformed as traditional collection data types. [This article](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754#reactive-programming-is-programming-with-asynchronous-data-streams) is a great introduction.

I won't convert this answer post into a tutorial, so let's go straight to the solution, which is shown below. I'm gonna be using the [RxJS](https://reactive-extensions.github.io/RxJS/) library, but there are other libraries for Reactive Programming in JS ([bacon.js](http://baconjs.github.io/) seems to be really popular too).

```
function settle(promises) {
  return Rx.Observable.from(promises).concatMap(function(promise, index) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise).
      map(function(response) {
        return { count: index+1, total: promises.length, state: "fulfilled", promise: promise, value: response };
      }).
      catch(function(reason) {
        return Rx.Observable.of({ count: index+1, total: promises.length, state: "rejected", promise: promise, reason: reason });
      });
  });
}
```

The function itself returns an observable, which is a stream of events. Namely, the events of each promise finished, either successfully or not. We can use that returned observable to listen to this stream (or to subscribe to it, if we're to adhere to RxJS terminology).

```
var results = settle(promises);

results.subscribeOnNext(function(results) {
  // process each result as it arrives
  // progress info can be extracted from results.count and results.total
});

results.subscribeOnCompleted(function() {
  // completion callback
});
```

And that's it. Much cleaner code, a more functional-programming approach. No need to keep state, everything expressed in a more declarative way. Just **what** we want to be done, **not how** it should be done.